# Expression Evaluation in 32 bit CPU

Tags: c, microcontroller

I am working with TIs 32 bit microcontroller TMS320F280049. I am using an external ADC for temperature measurement. The ADC output code is of 24 bit data, now I want convert this ADC output code to resistance value by using the following expression

`RTD = (1080 * ADC output code) / (4194304 * 16)`

and I wrote the code as follows,

```
int32 RTD = 0;
int32 adc = 0x005EEC17;

RTD = (1080*adc)/(16*4194304);
```

I wrote this expression as it is but got RTD value some random negative value instead of 100 which I am expecting. I wonder how to correctly evaluate the expression. I am beginner in coding any explanation that put into simple words will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "hex data to decimal form"? All integers in C are pure binary, though we can write constants with various forms of notation. Do you mean to scale the ADC input to what unit it is supposed to represent or what?

Comment: @Lundin  I am sorry that I did not phrase my question clearly. "Do you mean to scale the ADC input to what unit it is supposed to represent or what? " Yes this is exactly what I want. I want to convert this ADC output code to another value by evaluating the expression given in the original post.

Comment: @Lundin Instead of INT format if I use float for variable RTD and if I want to truncate my result to 2 decimal places what will be the code for that?

Answer (score 3):

`1080*0x005EEC17` overflows `int32`. Therefore you need to do the math in a wider type. You can use the `LL` suffix to make the literal `long long` which is at least 64-bit

```
int32 RTD = 0;
int32 adc = 0x005EEC17;

RTD = (1080LL*adc)/(16*4194304);
```

Answer (score 1):

An `int32_t` can only store values up to 2<sup>31</sup>–1 (approximately 2.15e9). Multiplying `1080 * adc` (approx. 6.7e9) will result an overflow. Here are some alternatives that seem to work with gcc:

```
uint32_t rtd = adc / 16 * 1080 / 4194304;  // Dividing first.
uint32_t rtd = (adc >> 4) * 1080 / 4194304; // Same as above.
uint32_t rtd = (adc * 1080.0) / (16 * 4194304); // Implicitly convert to double, so that larger values can be stored.
```

Comment: the first 2 methods lose precision. And the 3rd method is a bad idea on MCUs because double operations are done in software which doesn't only much much slower but also costs a lot of ROM space

Comment: @phuclv This particular part has some manner of FPU though, I think.

Comment: @Lundin its FPU has only single precision support so you'll still need software for `double`[